# Responsive emails - uneven columns?

Tags: html, email, responsive-design

I'm trying to convert an html emailer to be responsive. It currently has a full width (600px) header image, and under that, two columns, type on the left and a panel on the right. The columns are not a 50/50 split on the width, more like 70/30.

What I'd like to do is have the header image scale down and the right hand column wrap under the left hand one, but become the same width.

Hope I've explained it well enough - is this possible?

Thanks,
JIm

Comment: While you can certainly create a responsive template to do what you ask, I can't figure out way to do it without using media queries in css. CSS is problem if you expect any view consistency as many email clients (gmail, yahoo, outlook.com, etc.) strip some or all of the css. I suppose you could have your default layout be your most common and have the media queries there for the clients that support it.

Comment: Thanks Baldy - sounds like a good option. I thought that Gmail finally supported media queries now - or am I mistaken?

Comment: Email clients are notoriously bad at supporting CSS. What they do support is very limited.

Comment: Any ideas on what the css would be to expand the narrower right hand panel to be full width once it's hit it's break point and wrapped under?

Thnx J

Comment: You might find this link useful: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: I just blindly assume email clients don't support CSS. Even if some do, you still need to handle the ones that don't.

Comment: @jeff - thanks for that, that's pretty comprehensive!

Answer (score 0):

Might be with a big delay, but I just noticed your question while searching for a solution for responsive uneven columns with padding. 
I have managed to find a solution for uneven columns with no padding. Here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;" charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <style>
        /* resets */
        img{border: 0; height: auto; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none;}
        table, td { border-collapse: collapse; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;}
        body{height: 100% !important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; width: 100% !important;}
        div, p, a, li, td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }
        .ExternalClass * {line-height: 100%} 
        /* resets end */
        .imageFix {display:block; width:100%;}
        .mobile-separator { display: none!important;}
        .smalltext { font-size: 10px }

        @media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
            .container {
                width: 600px!important;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 525px) {
            .imageFix {width:100%!important;} 
            .mobile-separator { display: block!important;}
            .deviceWidth { width: 100%!important;}
        }

        /* yahoo only - USELESS FOR NOW */
        @media yahoo {
            body { background-color: #EFEFEF }
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body style="background-color:#EFEFEF; color:#000000;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">


    <!-- MAIN WRAPPER -->
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr>
            <td>
    <![endif]-->
    <table class="container" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#ffffff; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

        <!-- CONTENT STARTS HERE -->
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; font-size: 0;">

            <!-- 1 column no padding -->
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="deviceWidth">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#">
                        <img src="#" class="imageFix"  border="0" width="600" alt="image1" />  

                        <!-- mobile separator - should be hidden on desktop -->
                            <img alt="-" src="separator image 5px x 5px that will match the background" border="0" style="display: block;height: 5px" class="mobile-separator" />
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <!-- 2 columns 180px and 420px no padding -->
                <!-- the issue with this is that it shows a 200px centered image on gmail app -->
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="180" valign="top">
            <![endif]-->

            <!--  1st COLUMN -->
            <div style="width: 180px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" class="deviceWidth ">
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="#" class="imageFix" width="180" border="0" alt="image1" />  
                            <!-- mobile separator - should be hidden on desktop -->
                            <img alt="-" src="separator image 5px x 5px that will match the background" border="0" style="display: block; height: 5px" class="mobile-separator" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td><td width="420">
            <![endif]-->

            <!--  2nd COLUMN -->
            <div style="width: 420px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" class="deviceWidth ">
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="#" class="imageFix" width="420" border="0" alt="image1" />  
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->    
            <!-- //2 columns 180px and 420px no padding -->


            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- CONTENT ENDS HERE -->

    </table>
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- MAIN WRAPPER END-->

</body>
```

A few things to keep in mind:

1. the only problem I have is that on the Gmail App I can't make the
   image in the smaller column to go full width.
2. you need to have the width property for each image especially for the smaller column ( width="180" in your case ).
3. I would recommend to use a bigger image so that it will display nicely on mobile devices